# Appending string on every line and make new file

Tags: bash, list-manipulation

I need some direction on a bash that will take a list of words and append each word with words from another list:

**List 1**

```
1
2
3
```

**List 2**

```
!
@
#
```

**New Lists**
***(A)***

```
1!
2!
3!
```

***(B)***

```
1@
2@
3@
```

***(C)***

```
3!
3@
3#
```

How I started it:(I Suppose I should note I gave up having two input files to I went with a counter function instead.)

```
#!/bash/bin
CT=1000 
LIMIT=10000 
while [ "$CT" -lt "$LIMIT" ] 
do 
    echo $CT 
    sed -e 's/$/'$CT'/' -i 'INPUTFILE.txt' 
let "CT +=1" 
done
```

Comment: Try to include some code in your question and if it doesn't work, ask why

Comment: My output generally seems to either just make a list from 1000-10000, or else append $CT to every line in my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want numbered output files, try running a counter inside the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read -r suffix; do
   let i++
   sed "s/$/$suffix/" INPUTFILE.txt >file$i
done <SUFFIXFILE.txt
```

Note that `sed -i` will manipulate the original input file in-place.  You don't want that; you want the output in a new file.  So we remove the `-i` option and use the shell's redirection feature to indicate where to send standard output.

If you want to enumerate the destination file names, that's a bit trickier.  One solution is to add the destination file name to the suffix file

```
!        A
@        B
#        C
```

then read both tokens in the loop:

```
while read -r suffix outputfile; do
    sed "s/$/$suffix/" INPUTFILE.txt >"$outputfile"
done <SUFFIXLIST.txt
```

or if you want to embed this information in your script, use a here document:

```
while read -r suffix outputfile; do
    sed "s/$/$suffix/" INPUTFILE.txt >"$outputfile"
done <<____HERE
    !        A
    @        B
    #        C
____HERE
```

(The only Bash-specific construct is `let` for arithmetic, so the latter two scripts which don't use that can be run with `/bin/sh` instead of Bash.)

Comment: Amazing...Thanks So Much. I have just started fooling with computers beyond GUI stuff so really appreciated.